# how to validate code checksum at runtime

Tags: hash, runtime, executable, code-signing

I want to use code-signing certificate to verify code validity at runtime in Windows. For example, I have a service A, and another executable B that will call A. A needs to make sure only software having valid signature can call A. That is, every time B calls A, B needs to present its code checksum signed by the private key of the software vendor recognized by A. A has the public key of this vendor. The question is how does A make sure B presents the real signed hash (not someone else's) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. B is free to present whatever it wants. A has to either believe it or not. To be on the safer side A has to always believe B is hostile!